# Keypad backspace button not working when validate Textfield with special characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I try to validate the Textfield with special characters,

But, Pressing on delete button from keypad. Text filed data not removing.

I used this code to validate Textfield,

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
      NSCharacterSet * invalidNumberSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_!@#$%^&*()[]{}'\"<>:;|\\/?+=~`"];

     if([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:invalidNumberSet]isEqualToString:@""])
     {
        return NO;
     }
     else
     {
        return YES;
     }
}
```

please, suggest me how can i do that?

Comment: Are you want to prevent those special character or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Common function like this to implement your feature,

```
-(BOOL)isNumeric:(NSString *)pTmpString
{
    BOOL isValid = YES;
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_!@#$%^&*()[]{}'\"<>:;|\\/?+=~`"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [pTmpString length]; i++) 
    {
        unichar c = [pTmpString characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) 
            isValid = NO;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

and use it as

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    BOOL isValid = [self isNumeric:string];    
    return isValid;
}
```

This will not accept special characters from your keyboard to your textfield, though you press that letters from your keyboard.

If you have any doubt then tell me..I will help you..

Hope this will help for you..

Answer (score 0):

For Preventing Those special word i suggest this may help and there is so many option to prevent this type of the string match up one of the way i suggest to you which is below.

```
   if([string isEqualToString:@"_"] || [string isEqualToString:@"@"] || [string isEqualToString:@"#"] || [string isEqualToString:@"$"] || [string isEqualToString:@"%"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"^"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"&"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"*"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"("] ||  [string isEqualToString:@")"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"["] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"]"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"{"] || [string isEqualToString:@"'"] || [string isEqualToString:@"\""] || [string isEqualToString:@"\\"] || [string isEqualToString:@"<"] || [string isEqualToString:@">"]|| [string isEqualToString:@":"]|| [string isEqualToString:@";"]|| [string isEqualToString:@"|"]|| [string isEqualToString:@"/"]|| [string isEqualToString:@"?"]|| [string isEqualToString:@"+"] || [string isEqualToString:@"="]|| [string isEqualToString:@"~"]  ) {
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
```

And another option is Regex.
hope this may helping to you.